# Deprecation of NPAPI-Plugins

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, npapi

In the chromium blog it's mentioned that webpage-instantiated NPAPI plugins are not supported  anymore starting in january. (http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html)

Otherwise http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation says that:

> Apps and Extensions that use NPAPI plug-ins will not be affected by the initial January 2014 block.

Our extension uses a npapi plugin in the backgroundpage and also inserts one into the contentpages. Has anyone further informations about how the january changes will affect the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked pages don't say anything about stopping plugin support in january - they say most plugins will be blocked (i.e. made click-to-play).

The [Chromium article](http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation) says:

> Apps and Extensions that use NPAPI plug-ins will not be affected by the initial January 2014 block.
>   [...]
>   If your NPAPI plug-in is installed by a wrapper extension and then used by pages on the open web, it will not be affected by the initial January 2014 block. It will follow the Apps/Extension deprecation path instead.